# How to enable pip, QPython to write to Android filesystem?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, file-system, python

I have been following this guide to install youtube-dl on my Android phone.

http://www.arulraj.net/2015/11/download-any-videos-in-android-using-youtube-dl.html

However, when downloading the videos, I get the following error.

ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:

How would I be able to give write permissions to the pip console of QPython so I can write to a folder on /sdcard?

Running Android Marshmallow 6.0 with root access.

Answer (score 0):

You can create conf file in /etc/youtube-dl.conf . There you can specify the output folder by default.

Please specify an output folder where you have write permissions and it will work.